# How to connect server database without data loss/fail in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, http, synchronization

My project has to send and receive heavy data between server and mobile.

In case of internet signal weak, data loss may occur.

In an plan to use sqlite. And sync periodically with server database.

Can any one explain me how to use sqlite to sync with server db efficiently and notify to sqlite that local data has been updated in server db?

Any other suggestion for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a pretty broad request which has lots of avenues for answering. Have you made an attempt at setting up SQLite yet? How do you plan to connect to the server DB?

Comment: Initially storing values in sqllite. And then going to sync. if response code is 200 going to delete it from sqlite db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. first you have check the is **Internet connection** present or not , if yes go for the server communication if no then save your data in **Sqlite**  local database .
2. And for check the internet connection periodically if yes the database values are send to the server after successfully server communication remove that values from database.

**ConnectionDetector class :**

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

     private Context _context;

      public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
    this._context = context;
    }

    public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
      ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)       
          _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         if (connectivity != null) 
        {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) 
               for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                   if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }

      }
      return false;
    }
    }
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class LeadLogin extends Activity {

ConnectionDetector cd;
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

  editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
  cd = new ConnectionDetector(LeadLogin.this);
  isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

 if(isInternetPresent){

 // if internet connection present 
 //  communicate with server 

 }else{

 // internet connection not present
 // add values into database     

 }
 }

}
```

**StartService class :**

```
public class StartService extends Service {

Timer timer = new Timer();
private final int TIME_INTERVAL = 100000;
ConnectionDetector cd;
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(isInternetPresent)
    {
      doTimerThings();
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private void doTimerThings() 
{
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        public void run() {

             // check database value if here, if they are present then send to the server and delete from the database 
        }

    }, 0, TIME_INTERVAL);

}




@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}


 }
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It gave an idea about, 1)when to connect to server db. 2)when to store it in sqlite db and 3)sync periodically.

Comment: if this ans is helpful then upvote , it will be more helpful to other also

Answer (score 1):

Go through this tutorial..

http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

Remember--> when ever you are sending data to server, server will respond with `200` ok

(if successful) status 
code. Which tells you data has been send to server successfully. So, what you can do is you can delete data from your `sqllite` (if and only if `200` is received).

Comment: thanks a lot. It gave an idea about data successfully update in server db or not with response code 200.